# find $\mathbb E[X|Y]$ of the following joint pmf

Tags: probability, statistics

$$Y$$
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
X & 1 & 2& 3\\
\hline
1 & \frac{2}{15}& \frac{4}{15}& \frac{3}{15}\\
2 & \frac{1}{15}& \frac{1}{15}& \frac{4}{15}
\end{array}
$$

$\mathbb E[X|Y]=\sum_xxP(X|Y)=\sum_xx\frac{P(X,Y)}{P(y)}\ldots(1)$

where $P(y)=\sum_xP(X,Y)=$ 
$$Y$$
$$
\begin{array}{lcr}
 1 & 2& 3\\
\hline
\frac{3}{15}& \frac{5}{15}& \frac{7}{15}\\
\end{array}
$$

Now which value of $P(y)$ i will substitute in equation $(1)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula $(1)$ is actually not the formula for the conditional expectation ${\rm E}[X\mid Y]$ (which in fact is a random variable, and not a fixed number) but instead it is the formula for the conditional expectation ${\rm E}[X\mid Y=y]$. Using your formula, you can calculate ${\rm E}[X\mid Y=y]$ for $y=1,2,3$ and then use that 
$$
{\rm E}[X\mid Y]=\sum_{i=1}^3{\rm E}[X\mid Y=i]\mathbf{1}_{\{Y=i\}},
$$
where $\mathbf{1}_A$ denotes the [indicator or characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the set $A$, i.e. it is $1$ on the set $A$ and $0$ outside of $A$. This is just a short way of saying that
$$
{\rm E}[X\mid Y](\omega)={\rm E}[X\mid Y=i]\quad \text{if }\,\omega\in \{Y=i\}.
$$

Comment: Is that ${\rm E}[X\mid Y]=\sum_{i=1}^3{\rm E}[X\mid Y=i]$. What does $\mathbf{1}_{\{Y=i\}}$ denote?

Comment: @harry: See the edit. It's just saying that ${\rm E}[X\mid Y]$ is the random variable that is constant on the three sets $\{Y=1\}$, $\{Y=2\}$ and $\{Y=3\}$ with the constants being ${\rm E}[X\mid Y=i]$ for $i=1,2,3$.